# Getting null while converting string to date in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dates in the format '6/30/2020'. It is a string and I want to convert it into date format.

List of methods I have tried

```
Cast('6/30/2020' as date) #returns null
to_date('6/30/2020','yyyy/MM/dd') #returns null
```

I also tried splitting the string and then concatenating it into data.
After trying all this and putting all the possible combinations in the to_date function, I am still getting the answer as null.

Now I am confused as I have used all the functions to convert string to date.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format you used was incorrect. Try this:

```
select to_date('6/30/2020', 'M/dd/yyyy')
```

If you want to format your result, you can use `date_format`:

```
select date_format(to_date('6/30/2020', 'M/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

Note that `to_date` converts a given string **from** the given format, while `date_format` converts a given date **to** the given format.

Comment: How it is working for 12/30/2020 when the specified date format is 'M/dd/yyyy' and why 6/30/2020 is not working with 'MM/dd/yyyy' when 12/30/2020 is.

Comment: because if you specify MM, you need the month to have 2 digits. But 6 only has one digit, so the format is incorrect. Note that the number of M's means the **minimum** number of digits.

Comment: @BrownBatman see [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for more details on date string formatting.